# IIS Express works with Fiddler but returns 500 on remote API access C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, internal-server-error

I am able to make http request using fiddler in local host but I get Internal Server Error 500 when I try to connect from Android device in same WiFi network.

The frontend Is still accessible from remote device, it’s API that is giving this error.

What can be causing this error?

I already managed to get it to work in the past, not sure what has been changed in the meantime.

Comment: most likely because you haven't bound it to your local wifi IP address.  Which is slighly different from your loopback address

Comment: Even on a mobile device you should get a complete error page (more than Internal Server Error 500). Show a complete screen or use failed request tracing to learn the detailed error message, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis